# I want send email , but error in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage("test@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com", "header", "detail");
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;

  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
  client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
  client.EnableSsl = true;
  client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@gmail.com", "1234");
  client.Send(message);
  Label1.Text = "SuccessFull";
}
```

This is the error message I get:

> Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Server busy, closing transmission channel. Try again later

Comment: You should check the answers on [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32260/205233) and related posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

I will reference you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail) already existing post which explains briefly how to send an email using System.Net.Mail!

Furthermore after having followed the instructions on the link above be sure to check the option in [this](https://myaccount.google.com/security#signin) link for allowing google accessing your account to less trusted apps.
It's at the bottom of the page:
[image]

If you follow them step by step you' ll have no problem sending your email.
If I helped you solve your problem please vote my answer.